# Visual Studio Find and Replace content between html tags using regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, ide, find

I would like to use the equivalent of:

```
\<FooterTemplate.+?\<\/FooterTemplate\>/gms
```

In a Find and Replace regex for html/asp tags and their contents in visual studio 2015.
 
 The above regex will not work in VS, but does in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hO5dU5/1).

The closest I got with VS syntax was something like:

```
\</*FooterTemplate[ ]*.*\>
```

but only matches outside tags:

[image]

How can I edit the above regex to include contents in between the tag when searching?

Comment: I guess it will be `<FooterTemplate[\r\s\S]+?</FooterTemplate>`.

Comment: `[\r\s\S]+?` matches 1 or more ANY characters, as few as possible. From what I know, in VS S&R dialog, you need to add `\r` for it to span across multiple lines.

Comment: I see now. Could you put this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In VS search and replace tool, you can use `[\r\s\S]` character class to match any text spanning across multiple lines.

To match as few characters as possible to get a valid match, you need to use `*?` or `+?` lazy quantifier.

So, you can use

```
<FooterTemplate[\r\s\S]+?</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Awesome ! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You.